# Particle System (Collection) Rotation Direction

Tags: particles, system

I've been struggling to understand how to make my particle system objects face the direction that I want. In the example, below I am attempting to make all of the "pillar" objects to face outwards, away from the centre. I tried to rotate objects individually and change rotation settings inside the particle system but can't make it to work. Seldom, it does happen that my particles would face the direction that I want, but it seems to happen by sheer luck. What's the catch here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change orientation axis to normal

[image]

2. then in edit mode select all vertices of your object of the collection and press R Y 90 and position it right like this:

[image]

Then you see already that they are heading right. You have to do this for all objects in your collection. And of course you have to adapt your animation values (keyframes).

For your animation you have then to animate scale x to get your effect:

[image]

Be aware: i was lazy, i just corrected one bar.

here is the corrected file, so you can check it out:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Chris, would really appreciate it if you could have a look. Here is the file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/rV4jkrdw
Thank you

Comment: i changed my answer, sorry, i thought you had used hairs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: you are welcome, thanks for your blender file, without it, i could never help you....